# Centering elements in a BoxLayout

Tags: java, layout, jlabel, boxlayout

I cannot get `lblConInfo` to center, due to it's inline HTML. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Streamer extends JFrame {
    private static String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    private static String key = "123456";

    public Streamer() throws IOException {
        JPanel streamPanel = new JPanel();
        streamPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(streamPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setResizable(false);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setLocation(d.width - 200, 0);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        add(streamPanel);
        addComponents(streamPanel);
        setTitle("RDV");
        setVisible(true);
        Capture.getScreen();
    }

    public void addComponents(JPanel pane) {
        JLabel lblClipboard = new JLabel("test");
        lblClipboard.setForeground(Color.blue);
        lblClipboard.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        pane.add(lblClipboard);

        JLabel lblConInfo = new JLabel("<html><div align=\"center\">IP: " + ip + "<br>Key:" + key + "</div></html>");
        lblConInfo.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        pane.add(lblConInfo);

        JButton btnCopy = new JButton("Copy to Clipboard");
        btnCopy.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        pane.add(btnCopy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` in the constructor of `JLabel` as shown below:

```
JLabel lblConInfo = new JLabel("<html><div align=\"center\">IP: " + ip + "<br>Key:" + key
        + "</div></html>", BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
```

Read more about [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

snapshot

[image]